# Listbox of comboboxes and binding them WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a situation where i have a listbox of comboboxes , mainly it binds to a bridge entity so the object contains foreign keys . What i need to do is that i need to bind the display of the combos to the respective entities and their value members to the foreign key values in the bridge entity that i bind the listbox to.

the code i have now is :

```
<ListBox Name="lstServices" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Margin="2" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=wndMain,Path=DataContext}">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <ComboBox Name="cmbService" SelectedIndex="0" DisplayMemberPath="Name"  SelectedValuePath="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=FK_ServiceID}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllServices}" Grid.Column="0"></ComboBox>
                                <ComboBox Name="cmbService_Role" Margin="2,0,0,0" SelectedValuePath="{Binding Path=FK_ServiceRoleID}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllService_Roles}" Grid.Column="1"></ComboBox>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

I could manage to display the values that i needed but since the List Item context changed i can't get to the listbox itemSource .

Any help is appreciated
Bishoy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it :D  , here is how it should go

```
<ListBox Name="lstServices" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding MemberServices}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid >
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ComboBox Name="cmbService" SelectedValue="{Binding FK_ServiceID,Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=wndMain, Path=DataContext.AllServices,Mode=OneTime}"  SelectedValuePath="ID" DisplayMemberPath="Name"  Grid.Column="0" ></ComboBox>
                                <ComboBox Name="cmbService_Role" SelectedValue="{Binding FK_ServiceRoleID,Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=wndMain, Path=DataContext.AllService_Roles,Mode=OneTime}"  SelectedValuePath="ID" DisplayMemberPath="Name"  Grid.Column="1" Margin="2,0,0,0"></ComboBox>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```